# Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this error after switching to Python3:

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

```
result_file = '/tmp/search_{}.html'.format(hashlib.md5(item_name).hexdigest())
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make

```
result_file = '/tmp/search_{}.html'.format(hashlib.md5(item_name.encode()).hexdigest())
```

Seem should make

```
item_name -> item_name.encode()
```